# Using a model to create a drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

```
Asp.net MVC 4
Entity Framework 5
LINQ
C#
```

I have a ViewModel I am using already.  I am now adding my PermissionType model to my ViewModel.

This model represents a table in the database with the same name.

How do I turn this table into a `@Html.DropDownListFor()`

From the table for the 'text' I need 'name' from the database. 
From the table for the 'value' I need 'ID' from the database.

How do I turn that model into a usable drop down list from my controller to my page?

```
ForumBoard model = new ForumBoard();

model.TPGForumQuery = db.TPGForums;
model.ProPit_User = db.ProPit_User.Where(m => m.username == userName).FirstOrDefault();
model.TPGForumTopicQuery = db.TPGForumTopics;
// need help here
model.PermissionType = // a list of all of the permission in this table
```

Edit:

```
public class ForumBoard
    {
        public ForumBoard()
        {
            this.ProPit_User = new ProPit_User();
            this.TPGForum = new TPGForum();
            this.PermissionType = new List<ListItem>();
        }

        List<ListItem> PermissionType { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TPGForum> TPGForumQuery { get; set; }
        public virtual ProPit_User ProPit_User { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<TPGForumTopic> TPGForumTopicQuery { get; set; }
        public virtual TPGForum TPGForum { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Change your view model

```
class ForumBoard
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<ListItem> PermissionType {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Then, assign

```
ForumBoard model = new ForumBoard();
...
model.PermissionType = db.PermissionType
                         .Select(p=> 
                          new ListItem (){ Text = p.FieldForText, 
                                           Value= p.FieldForValue });
```

**Edit:** If your fields are non string type, unfortunately, you have to first call ToList() method.

```
model.PermissionType = db.PermissionType
                    //.Select(p => new {Text = p.TextField, Value = p.permissionID })
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(p=>  new ListItem (){ 
                                              Text = p.Text.ToString(), 
                                              Value= p.Value.ToString()});
```

Comment: I changed my view model to be a ListItem.  But for some reason it isn't showing up in my controller on model.  I tried to initialize it in the view model as well and the same result.  Any idea what i might be missing?  I'm adding the viewmodel to the original post as an edit.

Comment: Yeah my bad I just noticed the public was missing myself.  Thanks.

Comment: One more thing.  How do I convert the permissionID (INT) to a string?  I can't use .ToString() from within the .Select

Comment: Check my edit. First you need to call `ToList()` method as `ToString()` method is not supported.

Comment: That didn't fix it sadly.  It still says cannot implicitly convert type int to string.  And still cannot use .toString.  I'll throw it in google and see if i can find anything.

Comment: It won't let me use .ToString within .Select.  It says cannot implicitly convert type Ienumerable<listitem> to List<listitem> are you missing a cast?

Comment: Same error as before. =(  Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\jawilson\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\trunk\trunk\TPGProsPit2\TPGProsPit2\Controllers\ForumController.cs 30 21 TPGProsPit2

Comment: @James - After the Select do another .ToList() and try again.

Comment: Okay, you can sort it out either by changing your model to `public Enumerable<ListItem> PermissionType {get; set;}` or converting the query `ToList()` at the end. I have converted model in the answer.

Comment: I changed the mode. Enumerable didn't work, but I used IEnumerable and it worked so far.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it works now... I am answering without a compiler :).

Comment: That didn't work, it errors out when the page loads not.  For some reason linq to entities just won't accept .tostring.  Think I'll make another post for this specific issue. =(

Comment: Nm I figured it out.  All the same changes you had.  But have to remoe .ToString().  Instead have to use `Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.permissionID)` and now its working. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this method :

//Controller : 

    using(MyContext context = new MyContext() )
    {
       IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listItems = context.PermissionType.Select( p => new SelectListItem{ Text = p.FieldNameFor , Value = p.FieldNameFor });

       ViewBag.myList = listItems;

   }



/*
      Do other stuffs here and then return to View()
*/


// In your view :

@{
     IIEnumerable<SelectListItem> listItems = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.myList;
 }



  @Html.DropDownListFor("Name of DropDownList" , listItems )
```